# hiding and showing footer keeps on repeating on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide my footer whenever I scroll downward. What I do is that I make a slideDown animation then a hide function after it. But when I start scrolling down, it repeats the process and it becomes irritating. How do I make it only do it once after it is run once?

This is my code-

```
$('.empdetalye').scroll(function (event) {
var scroll = $('.empdetalye').scrollTop();
if(scroll > 50){
$('.footer').slideDown("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.footer').hide();
  });

}
if(scroll < 50){
$('.footer').slideUp("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.footer').show();
  });

}
});
```

Should I add something else to prevent it from repeating??

Comment: `scroll > 50` will fire many times and hence the repetition. You need to add a class say 'hidden' first time and check if footer has class hidden before the slideDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean value to check if the footer is hidden.

```
$('.empdetalye').scroll(function (event) {
var scroll = $('.empdetalye').scrollTop(),
    isHidden = false;
if(scroll > 50 && !isHidden){
$('.footer').slideDown("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.footer').hide();
    isHidden = true;
  });

}
if(scroll < 50 && isHidden){
$('.footer').slideUp("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $('.footer').show();
    isHidden = false;
  });

}
});
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Wow. great answer. but could spamming the scroll break it? or it would be rather hard to break it? What I mean is could there be possibilities that after too much scrolling the function might force the page to crash??

Comment: @marchemike I don't really think so. Modern browsers take care of that, and you don't need to.